# The four of us are brothers and sisters. Who are we? And why?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

For convenience, the four of us are nicknamed: **ONE**, **TWO**, **THREE**, and **FOUR** respectively.

What are our real names? And why do you think so?

We answered the following six questions to give you clues as to who we are.

To begin with, our real names are several letters long each.

---

- *1st Q. Regarding your nationality, are you British or Italian?*

  **ONE**: I guess I'm British.

  **TWO**: I'm British, too.

  **THREE**: Then, I'm Italian.

  **FOUR**: You'd say I'm Italian.

---

- *2nd Q. This is rather vague, but where do you go?*

  **ONE**: Go where? Hmm, nothing comes to mind.

  **TWO**: Perhaps, I'm the one who goes downwards?

  **THREE**: Then, I'm the one who goes upwards.

  **FOUR**: I go... Oh, that's right. I'm the one who goes wrong... in a sense.

---

- *3rd Q. Do you guys share a habit? If so, what is it?*

  **ONE**, **TWO**, **THREE**, **FOUR** (all of them unanimously): "N", "R", and "E"!

---

- *4th Q. What do you do on a daily basis?*

  **ONE**: I love sexy pole dance. In fact, a day doesn't go by without me doing it.

  **TWO**: I enjoy chasing THREE, but I never seem to catch up with her.

  **THREE**: I find myself constantly running from TWO. We're not destined to be together, I guess.

  **FOUR**: I'm of the same mind with ONE.

---

- *5th Q. What's your favourite number? The numbers used in your nicknames don't matter here.*

  **ONE**: I go with a two-digit number, twelve.

  **TWO**: Nine is my favourite.

  **THREE**: The same one with my nickname.

  **FOUR**: Do I need to spell it out? Isn't it obvious?

---

- *6th Q. You guys collaborate with each other all the time, right?*

  **ONE**: Yes, I enjoy doing "ONE ONE TWO", "ONE ONE THREE", "THREE ONE THREE", "ONE THREE" etc, but I don't do "THREE THREE ONE".

  **TWO**: I do "ONE TWO", "FOUR TWO" etc, but "THREE TWO" will never happen.

  **THREE**: I do "ONE ONE THREE", "FOUR FOUR THREE", "FOUR THREE" etc, but come to think of it, I don't seem to collaborate with TWO.

  **FOUR**: I get along well with TWO and THREE , but in this respect ONE remains cold and distant from me. I can't blame him, though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are

> The four directions:
>  ONE - North
>  TWO - West
>  THREE - East
>  FOUR - South

The questions:

1st Q. Regarding your nationality, are you British or Italian?

> Britain is North-West to Italy

2nd Q. This is rather vague, but where do you go?

> Go west means to die (go down = be buried)
>  Go south = go bad
>  But this probably is related to the position of the sun (East - rising, West - setting, South - changing direction)

3rd Q. Do you guys share a habit? If so, what is it?

> All end with "ern" when speaking of directions: northern, eastern etc.

4th Q. What do you do on a daily basis?

> The world spins on the poles (North and South) and as the world spins, West and East could be viewed as chasing each other.

5th Q. What's your favourite number? The numbers used in your nicknames don't matter here.

> Directions on the clock

6th Q. You guys collaborate with each other all the time, right?

> Mixed directions like NE, NEE etc. There is never something like EEN or NS.

Comment: To pajonk: Excellent! Your answer for who we are is just a little bit off the mark, though you're almost (99%) there. And in this regard, a little correction is needed to your solution bit of the 3rd Q. Finally, could you complete your explanation of the 2nd Q?

Comment: @Password-ProtectedKor I thought if leaving the anwer without the suffix "ern", but I coudn't find any explanation for the 3rd Q. Any hints?

Comment: To pajonk: Exactly! If you shorten your answer that way, the explanation bit of the 3rd Q will change accordingly, right? I assume that the phase "HAVE something in COMMON" threw you off a bit. As for TWO and THREE in the 2nd Q, the movement of that particular thing you've mentioned is the correct interpretation. Could you put the finishing touches to revealing who we are, once and for all?

Comment: To pajonk: The four of us don't have "N&R&E" in our real names, but rather these three words can be ***ed to the end of our names. The 3rd Q implies that the four of us have the ACT of doing that in common.

Comment: Ok, so just like I wrote in my last edit ;-)

Comment: To pajonk: Precisely! The four of us are curious: Which of the six questions gave the game away, put you on the right track?

Comment: The clock one. Really good riddle BTW, thanks for it!

Comment: To pajonk: On behalf of ONE and FOUR who just got back to doing pole dance, we TWO and THREE would like to add that we're glad you've enjoyed our riddle. Have a good day!